# Pig UDF not being able to filter words

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a file with tweets i want to extract all tweets with my filters however i get an error

```
public class TweetFilter extends FilterFunc {
    static List<String> filterList;

    TweetFilter() {
        filterList.add("sick");
        // Many More Filters
    }

    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            String str = (String) input.get(0);
            if (filterList.contains(str)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}

B = FILTER A BY UDF.TweetFilter($0);
```

`Error : could not instantiate 'UDF.TweetFilter' with arguments 'null'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the entire code then your `filterList` will be null resulting in a `NullPointerException` when calling `filteList.add("sick")`.

To resolve this, modify the line

```
 static List<String> filterList;
```

to

```
List<String> filterList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Also, make your constructor `public`.

`Could not instantiate` is usually the error message you get when something goes wrong when calling the UDF's constructor.

Comment: Yes this is my complete code how do i resolve this NullPointerException

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Ever after you suggestions i am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should register the jar which contains your filter before trying to call it from your pig script, if you haven't done so already

Try adding:

```
register myudfs.jar;
```

As explainded in de UDFManual http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual